# STM32F030F4 Timer3 doesn't work

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, stm32f0

I use STM32F030F4 in TSSOP-20 package and the timer doesn't work.
I try to find an example for STM32F103 and it work very good.

Here is the code sample that I use:

```
RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM3,ENABLE);

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_Config;
GPIO_Config.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6;

GPIO_Config.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
GPIO_Config.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Config.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_Config.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;

TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef timer;
TIM_OCInitTypeDef timerPWM;

TIM_TimeBaseStructInit(&timer);
timer.TIM_Prescaler = 0;
timer.TIM_Period = 100;
timer.TIM_ClockDivision = 0;
timer.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM1, &timer);

TIM_OCStructInit(&timerPWM);
timerPWM.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
timerPWM.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
timerPWM.TIM_Pulse = 50;
timerPWM.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;

TIM_OC1Init(TIM3, &timerPWM);
TIM_Cmd(TIM3, ENABLE);

TIM3->CCR1 = 50;
```

Comment: Your STM32F0 is substantially different from an STM32F1, especially with regard to how GPIO alternate functions are configured.  Your TSSOP-20 would be one of the lowest end variants of the chip, so it's important to check which peripherals may be deleted - however you are in luck, timer 3 is there, it is timers 6, 7, and 15 which are not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Timer 3 initialization code as generated by the STM32CubeMX:

```
/* TIM3 init function */
void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 5;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 400;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim3);

}
```

And within the HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim3) here is the related code to the pin initialization:

```
__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
/**TIM3 GPIO Configuration    
PA6     ------> TIM3_CH1
PA7     ------> TIM3_CH2 
*/
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = PWM_ISO_Pin|PWM_LED_Pin;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_TIM3;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

I noticed that you're missing this statement: 'GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_TIM3;' which means that you set the pin as Alternate_Function but forget to set *which* AF it should be mapped to.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail post. I havn't used HAL library yet, so it's time to try :)

Comment: And one more about GPIO structure:

typedef struct
{
  uint32_t GPIO_Pin;                                                   

  GPIOMode_TypeDef GPIO_Mode;

  GPIOSpeed_TypeDef GPIO_Speed;   
  GPIOOType_TypeDef GPIO_OType;  
  GPIOPuPd_TypeDef GPIO_PuPd;   
}GPIO_InitTypeDef;
It doesn't has Alternate_Function field, but all other field I initialized.

Comment: I tried this code, but it completely doesn't work.
I don't know, maybe the MC is not work correctly and I should replace it.
But write 1 to pin_0 is work perfect. Anybody has some ideas?